# Disconjugate Equation- Choosing a Beta in the Interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question regarding the solution to the following question.

For which $\alpha$ will the equation $x''+9x=0$ be disconjugate - that is, no nontrivial solution will have two or more zeros - on $J=[0,\alpha)$?

The general solution is $c_1\cos(3t)+c_2\sin(3t)=c\sin(3(t+a))$? Given any $0<\beta<\alpha$, $x''+9x=0$ is disconjugate on $[0,\beta]$ $\iff$ there exists a positive sol'n of $x''=9x=0$ on $[0,\beta]$.

For any $0<\beta<\pi/3$, let $x=\sin(3(t+a))$, where $a = \frac{1}{4}(\frac{\pi}{3}-\beta)$, then $x(t)>0$ in $[0,\beta]$ and x is a solution of $x''+9x=0$. Therefore, x is disconjugate in $[0,\beta]$ and x is a solution of $x''+9x=0$. Therefore, $x''+9x=0$ is disconjugate in $[0,\beta]$ for all $0<\beta<\frac{\pi}{3}$. On the other hand, if $\beta\geq\frac{\pi}{3}$, then $x(t)=sin(3t)$ has at least two zeros in $[0,\beta]$. Thus the eq $x''+9x=0$ is disconjugate on $J=[0,\alpha)$ only for any $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{3}$.

My question follows below:

Why do we choose a $\beta$ in the interval $[0,\alpha)$?

Comment: You should probably define disconjugate, I found one meaning in the literature and it doesn't seem to make sense given what you say here.

Comment: The definition is that no nontrivial sol'n of the equation will have two or more zeros on the interval